# How do I remove delay between dispatchTouchEvent and subview's onClick?

Tags: android, events, layout

I have a custom View subclass to which I render my graphics, and another View subclass (actually a subclass of LinearLayout) which I sometimes use for overlaying graphical information. This second view contains an ImageView which I use as a button to trigger an event.

As I have it implemented, there's an unexpected delay between the first view receiving the onTouchEvent and calling dispathTouchEvent() on it's child view, and the ImageView's onClickListener's onClick() getting called. Here's the relevant code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if ( getPopupRect().contains(event.getX(), event.getY()) )
    {
        // translate to relative coordinates
        PointF popupOrigin = getPopupPoint();
        event.setLocation(event.getX() - popupOrigin.x, event.getY() - popupOrigin.y);
        mPopup.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    ...
}
```

The subview's onClick() method is not called until I touch and release the "main" view.

The Question: how can I remove or minimize this delay, so that onClick() is called in a reasonable amount of time, without further user action?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526763/7315640

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a "click" consists of both a press, and a release event. Thus you  will never get a click-event unless you also release the button.
Use an OnTouchListener on the childview, as you do on the parent view - then you'll be able to get the same event.